# why i can't do anything in my application when Jbutton is pressed and performing its defined function in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe

this is how I'm trying to accomplish this:

```java
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Hello there");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                panel.updateUI();
            }
});
```

I set Enter button as the default button so when I keep pressing it the button press maybe 100 times or more but because I'm using `Thread.sleep(1000)` it takes some time so I have time to type in my JtextField or even close the window but can't do anything.

also, I tried to put `btnNewButton.addActionListener()` in the run method of a thread but no difference.

```java
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                         System.out.println("Hello there");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        panel.updateUI();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
thread.start();
// I used try catch block in real code
```

can anyone help me to solve the issue?

**I'm creating this application in eclipse using windowsBuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of something that is called EDT - the Event Dispatch Thread.

This special purpose thread is responsible for all the events in your GUI - including drawing (refreshing) and interactions (button click). This means, that exactly the same thread is used to draw your application as the one that is used to execute `actionPerformed` code. Since you are literally halting that thread for some amount of time, your application will be non responsive for that exact period of time.

Whatever is being executed on user interactions should be short and execute fast for the reason of not blocking the application. If you need to do some heavy stuff, there is a facility for that purpose called `SwingWorker` that allows you to easily do some processing in the background thread (pool) and schedule UI updates during execution (like update of progress bar)

In your second "thread" snippet, your thread is not doing anything beside adding `actionListener`  to the button, and then it terminates (probably after less than 1ms ;)) - action callback is still executed by the EDT. If you would `start` that custom thread from inside of `run` method - then it would be indeed in parallel and GUI would not be frozen - but again, `SwingWorker` is the way to go here.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! but do you know how to avoid that? I mean like every windows application I want to be able to at least close my program with the red "X" button even if it's doing a heavy task?

Comment: This is complex operation - first you must signal/stop all background processing, then you close your main frame. Without that, if your threads are non-deamon trhreads, they would keep the application alive (and keep doing whatever they are doing) even when the main windows is disposed.

Comment: @nitind Well !! because I'm new to java and there's a lot of new concepts so please give me some time to see if it works or not

Comment: @Antoniossss actually originated this answer.

Comment: WOW COOL!!!! This is exactly what I wanted. thanks for clarifying. sorry, I don't have enough reputation to like it but it deserves it.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what your code is supposed to do, but if you want to press the button and then 1000ms later it will check your field you should do something like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("before 1000ms");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("after 1000ms");
                System.out.println("Reading the text field ...");
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        System.out.println("after the thread");
```

Output:

```
after the thread
before 1000ms
after 1000ms
Reading the text field ...
```